# What is the difference between using && or typing the second command on the next line in bash script?

Tags: bash, boolean-logic

For example,

```
for files in ../parentdir/*data.txt
do
    command1 > output.txt && mv output.txt $path
done
```

Versus,

```
for files in ../parentdir/*data.txt
do
    command1 > output.txt
    mv output.txt $path
done
```

Versus

```
for files in ../parentdir/*data.txt
do
    command1 > output.txt | mv output.txt $path
done
```

Is there a difference in the flow of these scripts? If my command1 (using a program I can't change) creates output.txt file first and continuously adds/edits the file before it completes, how do I ensure that once the output.txt is completely done I can safely move the file to the correct directory? This would be a lot easier if the output.txt file name changed in anyway once completed but unfortunately it does not.

Answer (score 1):

When using `&&`, if the first command fails the second one would never execute.

In your second variant, the second command will always execute, no matter the result of your first command.

The idea, to make the execution of the second command dependant on the result of the first command: You can't move `output.txt` if it hasn't been created yet.

Comment: So then when I see my files don't move sometimes, it means the first part just failed. Interesting, have no idea why it would fail. Something I have to check on.

Comment: But what about when the file is created first but stuff is getting added to it, then it will automatically move the file? I'm using a program that will create the file first and continuously add/edit the file as it conducts various analyses. How to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

The `&&` will cause the second command to execute only if the first succeeds.

It's basically the same as:

```
command1
if [ $? = 0 ] ; then
    command2
fi
```

(where the `$?` is the exit value of `command1`, which should be zero on success)

Comment: One more alternative writing: `if command1; then command2; fi`

Comment: (...and the latter one, proposed by Wiimm, is much better practice --  checking `$?` lends itself to bugs, as when someone adds a `echo` for logging and doesn't realize they're changing the behavior of a conditional that happens later).

Comment: What about using a pipe "|" instead of && ? Does that also mean the mv command will execute regardless if command1 fails or not?